# Investigating convergence under the condition $|a_{n+1}-a_n| \le t^n$ for some number $0<t<1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Problem: Let $(a_n)_n$ be a sequence with the property that, for some number $0 < t < 1$ and all $n \in N$, we have $|a_{n+1}-a_n| \le t^n$. Investigate whether the sequence converges.

I am not sure about the answer but I thought maybe $a_n=log(n)$ type of a sequence would satistfy this inequality and still diverge because its growth rate decreases as $n$ gets bigger. I can see that the condition will be $|log(n+1)-log(n)| = |log(\frac{n+1}{n})| \le t^n$ but I cannot find a compatible base for the log and I cannot show that this holds for all $n$.

Thanks for your effort and time.

Comment: The sequence you took does not satisfy the condition.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I was thinking that log would satisfy the condition. Because log's growth rate decreases and $log(n+1)-log(n)$ gets smaller as n increases, but now I think it is not enough to be smaller than $t^n$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ and let $N$ be the smallest natural number such that

$$\frac{t^N}{1-t}<\epsilon$$

For any $N\leq m<n$ we have

$$|a_n-a_m|=|(a_n-a_{n-1})+(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})+...+(a_{m+1}-a_m)|$$

$$\leq |a_n-a_{n-1}|+|a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}|+...+|a_{m+1}-a_m|$$

$$\leq t^{n-1}+t^{n-2}+...+t^m=\frac{t^m-t^n}{1-t}<\frac{t^m}{1-t}\leq \frac{t^N}{1-t}<\epsilon$$

Thus, $a_n$ is Cauchy and therefore converges.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

Assume there exists $ t\in(0,1)$ such that

$$\Bigl(\ln(1+\frac 1n)\Bigr)^\frac 1n\le t$$

or,

$$\frac 1n\ln\Bigl(\ln(1+\frac 1n)\Bigr)<\ln(t)<0$$

but, using Taylor expansion
$$\ln(1+\frac 1n)=\frac 1n(1+\epsilon(n))$$
and
$$\ln(\frac 1n(1+\epsilon(n)))=$$
$$\ln(1+\epsilon(n))-\ln(n)$$
we prove easily that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n\ln\Bigl(\ln(1+\frac 1n)\Bigr)=0$$
So, the condition $$|a_{n+1}-a_n|<t^n$$ is not satisfied when $ a_n=\ln(n) $.